# Problem with HTTPS via VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a very strange problem and I would like to find a starting point to solve it.

The problem appears on my laptops with Ubuntu (16.04 and 19.04) when I turn on VPN (network-manager-vpnc) **but only on my parent's WiFi**. And that is a super strange thing to me. When I switch to tethering on my phone then everything (except very weak GSM signal:]) is fine. Moreover it seems that problem is only with HTTPS connections. curl hangs on TLS:

```
$ curl https://www.onet.pl/ -v
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55cd601785c0)

... <Expire in... repeated many times>...

* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cd601785c0)
*   Trying 213.180.141.140...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55cd601785c0)
* Connected to www.onet.pl (213.180.141.140) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

But when HTTP used:

```
$ curl onet.pl
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

it returns a response.

Any idea what may be wrong? Please let me know if you need more info to help.

Comment: @pLumo Not sure if I understand your question correctly but everything works fine if I connect to the VPN using any other WiFi

Comment: ah yeah sorry, then my comment does not apply ...

Comment: What do you mean "turn on VPN" - do you actually connect to a VPN provider ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl Yes. I connect to my company's VPN.

Comment: did you have a chance to try the MTU size ?

Comment: Does it happen to all websites? Well I guess this is more VPN provider related issue, I can reproduce the same issue with NordVPN, actually could have it seems fixed now when the CyberSec feature turned on some https websites endlessly loading or not loading at all but on the phone works perfectly fine xD that is weird agree and if I turned that feature off it loads fine. I guess that is closely similar to what you are experiencing.

Comment: Also if you have Firewall ON then turn it off some VPNs may misbehave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because the WI-FI router drops packets.
It happens when the size of the packets are to big.

try lowering your MTU size.

If your wifi interface name is wl0:

```
 sudo ifconfig wl0 mtu 1400
```

This setting is harmless and not persistent over reboot.
If it works and you accept the answer I will update with an explanation on why this happens :)

Comment: I agree that it sounds like packets are to blame and/or it is an OSI layer 4 issue based on the description given.

Comment: before you fiddle with the MTU size, you can verify this and find out the correct size with ping pakets of a defined size...i.e. `ping -M do -s 1471 www.onet.pl` would send a 1479 byte (1471 + 8 bytes header) ICMP paket and allow for some VPN overhead. `-M do` prohibits fragmentation, so its really one paket. If this goes through, its not about the MTU size. If you get a "message too long" then you can try and go down with the `1471` value until it works. Then set the MTU size a bit lower than that.

Comment: @tomodachi Sorry for delay. This is the first time I could test your solution again. It works. Almost:) I.e. It seems that setting MTU on `tun0` interface helped. If you could say something more about it it would be great:) I Hope you'll get bounty point when I accept your solution

Answer (score 0):

If your provider is using some sort of load balancer like RouterOS PCC (Per-Connection Classifier) using both-addresses-and-ports, that could be a problem because it doesn't play well with HTTPS.

Another possible reason is a transparent proxy, when a not-so-experienced network administrator tries to do a port redirect on packets which are destined to the 443 port. But I haven't tested it through, so I'm not 100% sure if it's the case. You can check it you're passing through a proxy with a simple telnet test, as presented in [here](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/How+to+identify+if+you+are+behind+a+Transparent+Proxy/14647/).